# SQL com join vazio

Tags: mysql

Eu preciso fazer esta query com MySQL retornando de acordo com ano.

Mas para os que não tem carga horária o campo deve ser `NULL`

[image: Modelo SQL]

Por exemplo: ano 2017

```
SELECT
    `turmas_has_estudantes`.`id`,
    `turmas_has_estudantes`.`numero`,
        `estudantes_identificacao`.`nome_completo`,
        `estudantes_carga_horaria`.`dias_letivos_anuais`,
        `estudantes_carga_horaria`.`ch_diaria`,
        `estudantes_carga_horaria`.`ano_letivo`
    FROM
        `turmas_has_estudantes`
    LEFT JOIN `estudantes_identificacao` ON `estudantes_identificacao`.`id` = `turmas_has_estudantes`.`estudantes_identificacao_id`
    LEFT JOIN `estudantes_carga_horaria` ON `estudantes_carga_horaria`.`estudantes_identificacao_id` = `turmas_has_estudantes`.`estudantes_identificacao_id`
    WHERE
        `turmas_has_estudantes`.`turmas_id` = 535 AND         `estudantes_carga_horaria`.`ano_letivo` = 2017 OR         `estudantes_carga_horaria`.`ano_letivo` IS NULL
    ORDER BY
        `turmas_has_estudantes`.`numero` ASC,
`estudantes_identificacao`.`nome_completo` ASC
```

Comment: Tire do where as condições sobre a tabela que quer que apareça. Condições no where na prática transformam left joins em inner joins.

Comment: @bfvaretto Se eu tirar o where aparecem outros anos
Eu preciso de apenas os anos de 2017 e se não tiver o campo ficar NULL

Comment: Tente mover este trecho do where para o ON: `AND  estudantes_carga_horaria.ano_letivo = 2017 OR estudantes_carga_horaria.ano_letivo IS NULL`

Comment: E aí, deu certo?

Comment: @bfavaretto Desculpe a demora. Eu tive que resolver uma coisa aqui antes
Deu super certo. Obrigado!!! Como coloca que a resposta está certa?

Comment: Eu vou colocar ali embaixo como resposta, este nosso diálogo está como comentário e não dá pra marcar

Comment: @bfvaretto Você usa Laravel? Eu quero fazer esta query com query builder

Comment: Aí seria outra pergunta. Poste uma pergunta separada sobre como montar a query com o query builder. Tem muita gente aqui no site que pode ajudar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você usa `LEFT JOIN` mas coloca condições da tabela relacionada no `WHERE`, o join pode acabar se comportando como `INNER`. Faça assim:

```
SELECT
    `turmas_has_estudantes`.`id`,
    `turmas_has_estudantes`.`numero`,
    `estudantes_identificacao`.`nome_completo`,
    `estudantes_carga_horaria`.`dias_letivos_anuais`,
    `estudantes_carga_horaria`.`ch_diaria`,
    `estudantes_carga_horaria`.`ano_letivo`
FROM `turmas_has_estudantes`
    LEFT JOIN `estudantes_identificacao` 
    ON `estudantes_identificacao`.`id` = `turmas_has_estudantes`.`estudantes_identificacao_id`

    LEFT JOIN `estudantes_carga_horaria` 
    ON `estudantes_carga_horaria`.`estudantes_identificacao_id` = `turmas_has_estudantes`.`estudantes_identificacao_id`
        AND (`estudantes_carga_horaria`.`ano_letivo` = 2017 OR `estudantes_carga_horaria`.`ano_letivo` IS NULL)   
WHERE turmas_has_estudantes`.`turmas_id` = 535 
ORDER BY
    `turmas_has_estudantes`.`numero` ASC,
    `estudantes_identificacao`.`nome_completo` ASC
```

Repare que foi preciso colocar parênteses na sua expressão original, porque ela usa `OR`.